# angular-ui: how to get data from "resolve" option when using $stateProvider.state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

The docs and stuff I've seen show how to use the "resolve" option but how do you get the data back?

I'm using meanjs.org v0.3.x

My route:

```
//Setting up route
angular.module('mymodule').config(['$stateProvider',
    function($stateProvider) {
        //start routing
        $stateProvider.

        state('some-path', {
            url: '/some-url',
            templateUrl: 'modules/mymodule/views/my-controller.client.view.html',
            resolve: {
                DataService: 'DataService',
                promiseToResolve: function(DataService){
                    return DataService.get({});
                }
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

Now how exactly to I access the "promiseToResolve" data in my controller? Docs don't seem to mention this.

Also, please let me know if the above code would break when it is minified.

Comment: It is documented in the [AngularJS $routeProvider API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider). Basically they become injectables for the controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('mymodule').config(['$stateProvider',
    function($stateProvider) {
        //start routing
        $stateProvider.

        state('some-path', {
            url: '/some-url',
            templateUrl: 'modules/mymodule/views/my-controller.client.view.html',
            controller: mySpecialController,
            resolve: {
                promiseToResolve: ['DataService', function(DataService) {
                    return DataService.get({});
                }]
            }
        });
    }
]);
```

You don't need the specific DataService line, so it's removed, and now in your controller (which you've specified in the above code) you can directly access the resolved data:

```
angular.module('mymodule').controller('mySpecialController', ['$scope', 'promiseToResolve',
    function ($scope, promiseToResolve) {
        $scope.dataResults = promiseToResolve.data;
    }
]);
```

As for minification, here we use [ngInject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677519/double-injection-in-angularjs-via-nginject-and-ng-annotate) which is great.